# How to trigger move event to some x or y position in Ext JS window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Help to trigger the Window move event on a button click. I have tried the following code snippet.

```
 Ext.getCmp(winId).x = 400;
 Ext.getCmp(winId).y = 100;
 Ext.getCmp(winId).fireEvent('move');
 Ext.getCmp(winId).doLayout();
```

Any help is must appreciated.

Comment: do you want to move the whole window?

Comment: yes. I want move the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using extjs6, take a look at this [extjs6 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setPosition)
You need to use **setPosition** method of component to move the window, optionally with an animation. The older releases of extjs have the same method too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change window position by specifying "left"-"top" coordinates in `setPosition` method

```
Ext.getCmp(winId).setPosition(400,100);
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer else everybody will flag you